# Doubt about grounding loop and shielding

Tags: analog, oscilloscope, grounding, shielding, ground-loop

Good morning,

first at all I want excuse me for my english and my inexperience.
I have working with complex setup (osciloscope+SMU+Waveform generator+ some circuits and shielding cage) and now Im starting to learn about the effects of the grounding loops and shielding cables.
Im starting to identify this effects in the osciloscope but when I think about the possible grounding loops I see ground loop every where.

For example if I have a circuit connected to a SMU (1 gnd) and then I read it on oscilloscope (2 gnd), is this a ground loop?

If I have a shielding cable and connect the shield to GND, is this another ground loop?

The ground loop isolator work for that situation? Should I remove the GND from the oscilloscope?

Im very confused. With this post I want to open a chat to speak about it, I see a lot of people with the same question and maybe We can make a great compilation.

Best regards.

> Eddits:
> That are some photos from some test I did with the oscilloscope:

This example is with the own generator of the oscilloscope (I wait a signal like that, without oscillation)
[image]

This with the waveform generator
[image]

And this joining the gnd of the oscilloscope with the waveform generator (Other joint)(It's reduced)
[image]

For example We measure the signal of a Silicon photomultiplier, We have a opamp for that purpose (This is no the problem), and the output of single photon detection is around 7-11 mV, and the noise its usually around 4-7 mV.

This oscilation of the photos is amplied too.

Comment: If the wires form a loop then it is a loop. You might want to draw a diagram. You should never remove GND from oscilloscope as that creates more problems such as electrical safety. This is a Q&A site so don't open a chat, ask a specific question and you get a specific answer. If there are already same questions then this may get closed as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but for example If I used a oscilloscope and a SMU and a shielding cage, all conected to GND, how can i remove this loop? Our signals are very small (5-10 mV) and some ground noise are (4-6 mV) so a small percent of the signal is lost, any idea? and sorry for propose a chat.

Comment: Your noise level is more than 20 times lower than your signal. For a digital signal that's more than good enough. Especially digital scopes will always show some level of noise.

Comment: And your noise is not at 50 Hz either?! So looks like ground loops are not your problem

Comment: No no no, this a pulse for testing, my signal is around 7-10mV and the oscillationg (with the amplification) is around 4-7  mV

Comment: And I cant replicate the signal I want because I need to use nitrogen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect your circuit's "Ground" node to several other devices' "Earth" nodes, then you form, what is conventionally known as a ground loop, because the wiring in your building completes the loop from one device to the other.

In terms of shielding, **ground loops are *good***, because they are most effective at remaining at a low impedance everywhere and equilbrating the shield's potential everywhere. Therefore, one should always aim to connect the shield to a stable (low-impedance) reference potential at as many points as possible. One common choice for this potential is the protective Earth (PE) contact of the installation wiring.

***BUT***, unfortunately very many devices use the shield contact as return conductor for their signals. This is very prevalent in audio signalling, but also in coaxial signalling used for scopes, waveform generators etc. Strictly speaking, this bad signalling practice is to blame for mains frequency interference in signals, and not the ground loops themselves. What happens then, is that 50 Hz current through the shield appears as signal voltage, because the devices measure the signal voltage with respective to their local shield potential.

In a good world, all signalling would be differential, and noone would suspect ground loops of being anything to worry about. But here we go again, in the 234256th question about the detrimental effects of ground loops.

If you which to (or have no choice but to) abuse shield conductors as signal return conductors, you can either just live with the mains interference. Maybe it is anyway not within your signal bandwidth.. Or you can break the ground loops with galvanic isolation, such as this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvWdD4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitor here is optional. It strongly improves the EMC and shielding at high frequencies, but it permits a very small 50 Hz current to bridge the transformer again.

Note that this will only work for AC signals. If you have to get rid of mains interference in precision circuits at very low frequencies or DC, you will have to resort to differential signalling.

Comment: I will edit my post with more information.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

It depends

## Longer answer

Ground loops are a difficult topic. In many cases you don't have to care about them, but sometimes they hit you in the face.

If it's a problem in your case is impossible to say as there is not enough information provided.

First off, we have to look at definitions. We have GND which is generally considered the reference and 0V potential of our cicuit.

Then we have earth to which GND can be connected (but does not have to be necessarily). Earth is the 3rd pin on the wall outlet. On most oscilloscopes, GND is connected to earth internally.

Most DC power supplies are floating, which means, that GND is not directly connected to earth (but will have a capacitive connection anyway but you don't have to care about that in most cases). Function generators on the other hand often have their GND connected to earth.

So: check if your power supply GND is connected to earth. This can be done with a simple continuity tester. It's good to know.

Now, what are the consequences?

Probably none! As long as you provide a good GND path for your signal (means: connect the GND of your oscilloscope, your power supply and the circuit with as short a connection as possible) you don't have to care about GND loops too much. Try to connect in a [Star-Configuration](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/staying-well-grounded.html) but don't be religious about it.

Just never forget that every measurement needs two connections. One GND and one signal. It's tempting to just hold the probe of your oscilloscope to a point in your circuit and forget GND. This even gives you a signal in many cases (remember that "capacitive coupling" mentioned earlier?). If your oscilloscope has more than one channel, only connect one GND (they are connected internally). There are cases where you will need to connect a GND for every signal but that's outside of the scope of this basic answer.

Comment: wow.. thanks to people like you It's why I love this forums.. 

First:
The noise is a problem.. I will post a photo on the main message.
I have read a lot of people saying that almost situation Its not a problem but Its not for me.
For example, my circuit have 2 GND pin, so I connect all the negatives and GND to the power supply GND.
When I read on oscilloscope there is another GND, do u think maybe a solution is disconnect gnd on power supply and connect only the GND from the scope?
We are working with low voltages but sometimes We got 40-60 volts and some mA.